# PyQT6: the ui automatically close immediately

Tags: python, pyqt6

im new to PyQT. working on a simple UI transition.

my logic was:

> If createacc button is pressed
>
> Navigate to aboutUI

The issue is as soon as I press login button, I can see something open for extremely brief moment. Windows gets closed but program is still running

P.S im using vscode

this is the login UI code

```
class loginUI(QDialog, UIprompt):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        currentUI = self
        #it has a default bg and icon path :)
        UIprompt.setup_ui(self, 'Shopping Cart - Login Account',350,470)

        #buttons
        self.createacc = QPushButton(self)
        self.createacc.setText('Sign Up')
        self.createacc.clicked.connect(self.go_to_createacc)

        self.login = QPushButton(self)
        self.login.setText('Login')
        

        login_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        login_layout.addWidget(self.logusername)
        login_layout.addWidget(self.logpass)

        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addWidget(self.login)
        button_layout.addWidget(self.createacc)
        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        main_layout.addLayout(label_layout)
        main_layout.addLayout(login_layout)
        main_layout.addSpacing(50)
        main_layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        main_layout.addSpacing(50)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def go_to_createacc(self):
        self.navigate_to_ui(self,aboutUI)
```

the function used for transition:

```
@staticmethod
def transition_to_ui(current_ui: QDialog, new_ui: QDialog):
    if current_ui and isinstance(new_ui, QDialog):
        current_ui.close()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        new_ui.show()

@staticmethod
def navigate_to_ui(current_ui: QDialog, ui_class: QDialog):
    new_ui = ui_class()
    UIprompt.transition_to_ui(current_ui, new_ui)
```

and the remaining code(for aboutUI)

```
class aboutUI(QDialog, UIprompt):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        UIprompt.setup_ui(self, 'Cart', 400, 550)
        self.backbutton = QPushButton(self)
        self.backbutton.setText('BACK')
        self.backbutton.clicked.connect(self.go_to_landing)

    def go_to_landing(self):
        from landingUI import landingUI
        self.navigate_to_ui(self,landingUI)
```

Comment: Your approach seems quite convoluted, and you're missing an important aspect: you're creating objects without keeping a persistent reference, so they get garbage collected. Also, you should *never* use blocking functions like `time.sleep()` in the main thread of a GUI environment.